# Validate email and send it to Lumen controller

Tags: php, controller, lumen

I'm trying to validated email with lumen controller. If email is entered correctly, it should pop out "valid" but at the current state its always "invalid" even with correct emails entered.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 class NewsletterController extends Controller
 {
  public function subscribe(Request $request)
 {
    $email = $request->query('email');
    echo $email;


    function valid_email($email) {

        return !!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);


    }

    if( valid_email($email) ) {

        return response()->json(["valid"]);



    } else {

        return response()->json(["invalid"]);

    }

}
}
```

AJAX Call via jQuery

```
 function msg() {
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
console.log(email);
var email2 = $('input[type=email]').val();
console.log(email2);
event.preventDefault();

$.get("newsletter/subscribe?email + $('input[type=email]').val()", function(data, status){
    console.log("data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
})
.done(function() {
    //console.log( "done" );
    alert("DONE");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
    alert("Fail");
})
.always(function() {
    //console.log( "finished" );
    alert("hz");
});
```

};

Form

```
 <form class="join-newsletter">
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" class="email-address">
    <input onclick="msg()" type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="submit-email button">
 </form>
```

Updated code: still showing data: invalid.

Comment: What is your route definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your ajax request could be changed to.

```
$.get("/newsletter/subscribe?email="+ $('#email').val()
```

The possible problem is here you don't send `email` value correctly to your controller.

Comment: hey! now its still spiting data: invalid.  I actually based that code on your older topic.

Comment: /public/?email=# comes out.

Comment: It should be ```$.get("newsletter/subscribe?email=" + $('#email').val(), function(data, status){```

Comment: Hey,, when i add that bit to my code. it does not work at all. 
it just spits out. ``.fail(function() ``

Comment: Please check Ajax response, and also update your route definition.

Comment: ``$app->get('newsletter/subscribe', 'NewsletterController@subscribe');`` my route.php 

ajax response seems fine, hmm. i'm missing something...

Comment: What is output of `YOUR_URL/newsletter/subscribe?email=test@gmail.com`? (Change YOUR_URL to correct value)

Comment: it comes out as test@gmail.com["valid"]

Comment: Hey, try ```$.get("/newsletter/subscribe?email=" + $('#email').val(), function(data, status){```, focus on ```/``` before ```newsletter```, and check browser console to see you call to above url which returned ```test@gmail.com["valid"]```

Comment: adding slash url goes wrong - ``myurl/newsletter/subscribe?email=manhumble19@gmail.com`` it should be ``myurl/public/newsletter/subscribe?email=manhumble19@gmail.com ``

Comment: Remove ```echo $email;``` in your action please